# Cannot delete TaskFolder with the same name twice in Outlook Rest Tasks API

Tags: outlook-restapi

We are using the outlook tasks API to delete a TaskFolder. 
If we create a folder and delete it all goes well. If we then create the folder again with the same name and then delete it again we get the following error when deleting:
409 (Conflict)
{"error":{"code":"ErrorFolderExists","message":"A folder with the specified name already exists."}}

This seems like a bug ?? It probably is moving it to an trashcan internally ? Also from the outlook.com site it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem, and you're guess is correct. Essentially you're trying to copy a folder into the "Deleted Items" folder that has the same name as a folder that already exists there. The workaround here would be to rename the folder with some reasonably unique value (like maybe append a timestamp to the name), then delete it.